# How to run crontabs with sudo R CMD BATCH?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, command-line

I would like to run a crontab every day at 12h. So I defined a path to my Script with the following syntax:
`00 12 * * * sudo R CMD BATCH /home/.../test.R`

In order to test that I just ran:

```
sudo R CMD BATCH /home/.../test.R
```

And get the message:

```
basename: extra operand ‘.R’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

I tried many combinations but nothing seems to work. Maybe one has an advice?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what you want to achieve with this cron ? May be we could help you more if we know know more. Thank you.

Comment: No hard feeling on close voter , Bro Ubuntu is A  Linux OS . And this question about linux. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to run a `R-Script` on daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following `Rscript filePath.R`

I mean your cron entry get modified as

```
00 12 * * * sudo Rscript /home/.../test.R
```

Let me know if any issues.

Comment: Perfect!!!!!THX Just one additional remark. Is there a way to pass a .txt file after `Rscript` like `00 12 * * * sudo Rscript --slave /home/.../test.R /home/.../errors/error.txt` ?

Comment: well , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808169/r-command-line-passing-a-filename-to-script-in-arguments-windows